# BluetoothHeadset - Can't access public method

Tags: android, reflection, bluetooth

On the following page I am browsing the android source code for the BluetoothHeadset object:
http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothHeadset.java

Now in my code after getting the BluetoothHeadset object, I cannot access the method:

```
public void phoneStateChanged(args...)
```

Does anyone knows why it's not accessible? I tried using reflection but without effect...

My code:

```
 protected BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener headsetProfileListener = new BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(int profile, BluetoothProfile proxy)
        {
            // mBluetoothHeadset is just a head set profile,
            // it does not represent a head set device.
            bluetoothHeadset = (BluetoothHeadset) proxy;
            bluetoothHeadset.phoneStateChanged(...); //this method doesnt get autocompleted or recognised
        }
    };
```

EDIT: I know the method isn't mentioned in the android docs, but it probably is in the source code and maybe is made private, also I run a Cyanogen rom where the function is declared...

It's an app to experiment around with bluetooth and sending notifications...

Also I'm new to using reflection, so maybe the issue lies here:

```
bluetoothHeadset.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("phoneStateChanged", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

That function isn't part of the API here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothHeadset.html

If its not part of the published API, you can't count on it.  It may not actually be in the version of the framework you're using.

Comment: I made an edit to my original post, I know it's not 100% supported but I'm trying to experiment with it...